# Ubuntu 17.04 multitouch gestures are not working on Macbook pro

Tags: multi-touch

Just updated to Ubuntu 17.04 and (three and four finger) multitouch gestures as described on the link below stopped working. They use to work fine on my macbook pro but stopped with the latest ubuntu unity install. is there a way to enable to again?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

Comment: I'm having the same issue since 17.04 on Dell XPS 15. Please mention me if someone found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar trouble on the (upgrade) install, but it worked fine from the live usb. Single touches are working fine (i.e., the screen is okay).

Comment: Gestures work fine in a guest session. So, gestures are not broken on the machine, only in the account that was created prior to 17.04.

Comment: It appears that the culprit is Google Chrome. Gestures work fine until I start Chrome. One chrome is started, it responds to some gestures (like two-finger scrolling) but window manager gestures do not work (like window resize). Quitting Chrome does NOT restore gestures, but logging out/in does.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem. I was actually using ubuntu on xorg. When i changed it back to regular ubuntu at the login screen it fixed my multitouch.